# Animal Identification from "leavings"

Tags: united-states, animal-identification, scat-identification

There's a couple of small piles, about 3 inches across on my mom's back deck on the outskirts of Terre Haute, Indiana in the US. The pieces are firm but flexible as if they are plant matter, not sure if it's scat or discard.

My mom has a crab apple tree in the yard. The piece I picked up did have that leathery feel of dried apple.

[image: closeup of one pile]

[image: both piles in view]

The home is in the outskirts of Terre Haute, Indiana US. The area has deer, raccoons, possum, fox squirrels, rats, mice and chipmunks.

Her yard has several gardens of ornamental plants. She has a couple of bird feeders out as well. They are a few feet away from the back edge of the deck.

The piles are closer to the back door and away from the edges of the deck. There's no garbage outside at all, the bins are kept in the garage which faces the front of the house.

The deck itself is about one foot above the ground and is about twenty feet long alongside the house and about twelve feet across. One side is right up against the house.

She was curious about what animal may have left the piles. I was curious as to whether or not they are scat or just left over roughage.

Comment: Welcome C Teegarden! This is an interesting and well-written question! Do those red droppings have berries in them? Scat with berries can narrow it down. Some animals, like your mom's, eat berries which they don't fully break down so they appear in the scat. Let us know. In the meantime, we'll be doing some research for you!

Comment: Thanks for the information! I have a couple of other questions. Is this deck attached to the house? Are there steps to where the droppings are? Is there garbage in that spot? Some animals will stay away from the house unless there's something yummy to eat! Some will climb, others won't. If you [edit] the information directly into the question, that would be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm going to delete my comments as they're no longer necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you confirm by observation:

This is sort of what I would expect to see from a squirrel eating.  Take a closer look and see if you can figure out if they are crap, or just cores and peels.   I've seen squirrels create large mounds of conifer scales.  They like to find a spot where they can watch the world while they munch.

Might also be a chipmunk.

The source fruit may also be mountain ash berries (big clusters of pea sized orange/red berries) or hawthorne (similar looking to crabapples.

Test:  Put a bunch of crabapples, or whatever other stuff you think might be the starting product on your bird feeder, and see what comes.

That said:  Indiana is a long way from Alberta.